# basic if statement 3 values in c++

Tags: c++

I am new and beginner in programming and dont quiet understand how to post my question here. Hope this works.
Anyways, im starting from basic and just learnt the "if" statement. But when i tried to create my own version its not working. My program  below is showing all three cout results even if i enter only one option(attack or run or hide). It was working fine when there was just one "if" statement. I tried the "else if" too but then it only printed out the result "you have attacked" no matter what i chose. :( I used the search bar for similar questions that might have already been answered but didnt find much that could help me.
If there are similar questions then i'd appreciate if you could point me towards it, although i'd really be grateful if you could point out what my mistakes are specifically.
Thnx~

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout<<"Welcome to the jungle!!!"<<endl;
cout<<"--------"<<endl;
cout<<"Enemies approaches! \n Choose your next move! \n";
cout<<"Attack / Run / Hide \n\n\n";

string choice;
cin>>choice;

if(choice=="Attack"||"attack")
{
    cout<<"You have attacked!"<<endl;
}
if(choice=="Run"||"run")
{
    cout<<"You start running!"<<endl;
}

if(choice=="Hide"||"hide")
{
    cout<<"You hide in a cave!"<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(choice=="Attack"|| choise=="attack")`

Comment: @manni66 'choice'

Comment: @SurajS compiled without errors in my brain ;)

Comment: Thnx for that quick reply. Didnt know i had to put "choice" after '||' operator too. hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(choice=="Attack"||"attack")
```

does **not** mean "if choice contains "Attack", or choice contains "attack", do the thing".

It means "if choice contains "Attack", or "attack" is true, do the thing".

In pseudo-code, you expect:

```
if choice is the string "Attack"
    or choice is the string "attack"
        do a thing
```

but the `or` splits the statement into halves, and the second half doesn't mention the variable `choice` at all. It breaks down more like

```
if choice is the string "Attack"
    or the string "attack" on its own is somehow true, whatever that might mean
        do a thing
```

Since `"attack"` is a pointer to a `char` array, being `true` means it is not `NULL`, which is always the case, so this branch is always entered.

To express what you mean, write instead:

```
if(choice=="Attack"||choice=="attack")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although i dont quiet understand it all atm,i am sure i will get it later on. :)

Comment: Got it. :) Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) (those are links to explanations).

Comment: Ah,I think i understood those links a bit....might have to go through again for some time.

Comment: quick question and sry for goin off topic a bit. But it seems i need to put std:: in front of string(tried in my above program), whereas int doesnt need std (i assumed its needed cuz both are datatype but i get error if i put std::int).  Is there a link or something which shows which terms i need to put std:: in front of? thnx

Comment: @Sanrai [Types that are built into the language do **not** need a namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). [Types from the Standard Library **do** need the namespace `std` prefix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) (e.g. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)). If you use types from other libraries, they will probably have a different namespace, e.g. [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/any.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
if(choice=="Attack"||choice=="attack")
{
    cout<<"You have attacked!"<<endl;
}
```

OR( || ) is a boolean operator.
 So Anything other than 0 gives an impression of 1 in boolean. Thus the syntax in `if` code is always executed. This is the reason for in the `else if` case first statement is always executed (and further statements are skipped).

Also, `using namespace std;` is a bad practice since it makes our code confined to just one std library. instead you must use `std:cout`;

Comment: Oh i see now what was goin with "else if". thanks.
uh using namespace std is bad practice?

Comment: Yes, because as a developer you will be working with many namespaces. Using namespace std confines you to just one of them. You could read about them here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm

Comment: @Sanrai if you found my answer useful please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to C/C++ world.**

As you have already read in tutorials or book, the content inside the parens of an `if` has to be a `boolean` value. Now, a lot of stuff can be converted automatically to `bool` and as a condition for an `if`.
In particular, anything that can be converted to an `int` will, in turn, have a `bool` value attached to it. Pointers are of such kind.

- If the value is different from `0` then the result will be -> `true`
- `0` otherwise.

Writing `if(choice=="Attack"||"attack")` you are telling the compiler to execute the content of the `if` either if the content of choice is equal to the string `Attack` or if the the pointer to the underlying `const char*` *attack* is not zero.

`attack` is a valid string which mean its value is not zero which in turn means you are getting a true out of it.
Same goes for all the others `ifs`. The second part of all you `if`s are `true` cause they are not `null` pointers.

Change the all the `if`s as the following: `if(choice=="Attack"||choice=="attack")` and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Ah.... i get it now i think. The ||"attack" is not read as string but as true or false.
Thanks a lot.